# How do I fetch rows from a MySQL database with multiple like combinations?

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch rows from a table having `WHERE` condition with multiple `LIKE` combinations,

I mean, for example, I have a field `description` in the table which has two rows

```
1. 'abc def hij klm'
2. 'opq rst uvw xyz'
```

My search text is `abc rst`. So I need a query with a `LIKE` condition that must produce both the rows, because the first row contains the string `abc` and second contains `rst`. I know I can use the `OR` in between two `LIKE` condition, but what should I do if the search text is too long because it has more words?

Comment: Explode your search text with space & go ahead. Or if you have tried anything post it.

Comment: What exactly you need ?

Comment: @Rikesh ..I know i can explode the search text and use OR for condition, is there another way to handle this..

Comment: You could always try regexp pattern matching: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: You can also use [REGEXP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm).

Comment: You may also want to look into MySQL's [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit painful, but one way to do it is with like and `substring_index()`

```
where concat(' ', description, ' ') like concat('% ', substring_index(@SearchString, ' ', 1), ' %') and
      concat(' ', description, ' ') like concat('% ', substring_index(substring_index(@SearchString, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), ' %') and 
      concat(' ', description, ' ') like concat('% ', substring_index(substring_index(@SearchString, ' ', 3), ' ', -1), ' %') and 
      concat(' ', description, ' ') like concat('% ', substring_index(substring_index(@SearchString, ' ', 4), ' ', -1), ' %')
```

The nested `substring_index()` return the nth item of the list.

If the codes you are looking for a real codes just glommed together in the `description` field, then you have bad database design.  You need an association table with a single row for each code.

If the description is really a text description, then you might really want full text indexing.  This would solve your problem using `match . . . against`.